# Populate and Pass a User-defined Table Type Parameter to a Stored Procedure All in One Step

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I have a stored procedure `uspTest` that accepts one user-defined table-type parameter `@params`. Say `@params` is made up of three ints, `FldA`, `FldB` and `FldC`.

I'd like to populate the table-type parameter and execute the stored procedure all in one step.

I tried:

```
    exec uspTest @params = values(1, 2, 5)
```

and

```
    exec uspTest @params = (select 1, 2, 5))
```

but neither works.

Is it possible? How?

Eventually, I'd like to pass in three or four rows in the table-type param, populating it with a select statement.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do it in one step?

Comment: Nope, not possible with a table type. If you aren't passing rows, why use a table type here? Use three variables.

Comment: @Siyual, I'm creating it for a downstream developer who has requested that it be done in one statement.

Comment: any source code to look at?

Comment: @JohnJoseph I could be mistaken, but I really don't think this is possible.

Comment: @SqlZim, I will be passing rows but to keep the question and answer simple I created a use case that requires just one.

Comment: I had hoped that just as one can declare and populate a table in one statement, this would be possible, too.  Knowing it is not possible is actually quite useful, so I upvoted the first response to that effect.